# How do I edit text out of an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

Here I want to remove all text in the boxes without affecting the background image. I tried using content-aware but couldn't get the expected result.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: To be honest, it looks like recreating the image from scratch is less work.

Answer (score 3):

This is not something that can be done with present content replacement technology. In order to "remove" the text, you will have to redraw the portion of the background that it covers. Using the clone tool at a small diameter and with slight blur would be where I would start. Sample nearby areas, then paint over the text. It will be a tedious process. The fact that the text in this image is casting a drop shadow makes the prospect even more tedious. It would honestly be far easier to simply start over from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

To make things easier and spare some (many) hours of work, why not simply create the arrow, add the image in a layer above the arrow layer and right click on it and select Clipping Mask!

From there on you only have some circles and boxes with text...and there you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself some service and obtain a fresh image and built it from scratch. It will be probably cost less than $20 or $5 if you use Fiveer.

e.g. from Shutterstock http://www.shutterstock.com/s/meeting+businesswomen/search.html?page=3&thumb_size=mosaic or these free resources http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/238646

Answer (score 0):

Okay if it is only the boxes you want then it is way easier and you will obtain a better result from making them yourself.

from what i can tell then it is really just a green circle placed above in the corner of a square. the circle has a white stroke about 4 pixels. the green square has a opacity level of about 80% and has a drop shadow effect. Now you are free to place any text you want inside and add it to any background image you want.

btw the circle has an opacity level of 100% from what i can tell.

hope this helps a little